# Kernel module to intercept system calls causes issues in execution of userspace programs

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, systemtap

I've been trying to write a kernel module (using SystemTap) that would intercept system calls, capture its information and add it to a system call buffer region that is kmalloc'd. I have implemented a mmap file operation so that a user space process can access this kmalloc'd region and read from it.

Note: For now, the module only intercepts the `memfd_create` system call. To test this out I have compiled a test application that calls `memfd_create` twice.

[SystemTap script/kernel module code](https://gist.github.com/InertFluid/0dc0034cf57a75522ef6eca20f520901)

In addition to the kernel module, I also wrote a user space application that would periodically read the system calls of this buffer, determine whether the system call is legit or malicious and then adds a response to a response buffer region (also included in the kmalloc'd region and can be accessed using mmap) indicating whether to let the system call proceed or to terminated the calling process.

[User space application code](https://gist.github.com/InertFluid/a0acc5a405de1227833bc70e13c018db)

The kernel module also has a timer that kicks every few milliseconds to check the response buffer for responses added by the user space. Depending on the response the kernel module would either terminate the calling process or let it proceed.

The issue I am facing is that after intercepting a few system calls (I keep executing test application) and processing them properly, I start facing some issues executing normal commands in the userspace. For example: A simple command like `ls`:

```
[virsec@redhat7 stap-test]$ ls
Segmentation fault
[virsec@redhat7 stap-test]$ strace ls
execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 30 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

This happens with every terminal command that I run. The `dmesg` output shows nothing but the `printk` debug outputs of the kernel module. There is no kernel panic, the kernel module and the userspace application are still running and waiting for the next system call to intercept. What do you think could be the issue? Let me know if you need any more information. I was not able to post any code snippets because I think the code would make much more sense as a whole.

Comment: Have you considered using the procfs probes for two-way communication with a stap script?  That way you don't have to do all that iffy embedded-C code.

Comment: I believe the EFAULT could come from kernel-side memory access errors caused by the stap (embedded-C) code, invoked from the context of the syscall trapping probe.